# data is not updated on product page with getX provider

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-getx, flutter-provider

I am trying to set the getX provider in my app to retrieve products data from firebase.
But when I open a new product page, data it's not updated and I see previous product's data.
I am still new to getX, and I wonder if I did all right, or I am missing something.

**ProductController.dart**

```
  class ProductController extends GetxController {
   Rx<Product?> selectedProduct = Rx<Product?>(null);
// Method to fetch a single product by its ID
  void fetchProductByID(String category, String productID) {
    _services.userRef.doc(_services.getUserID())
        .collection('Categories')
        .doc(category)
        .collection('products')
        .doc(productID)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        var product = Product.fromDocumentSnapshot(snapshot);
        selectedProduct.value = product;
      } else {
        selectedProduct.value = null;
      }
    });
  }
```

Declared controller on **main.dart**

```
 class MyBindings extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<UserController>(() => UserController());
    Get.put<ProductController>( ProductController() );
  }
```

**ProductPage**

```
     final ProductController _productController = Get.find();

    @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _productController.fetchProductByID(widget.catID, widget.docProdId);
  }
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Product? product = _productController.selectedProduct.value;
    return Scaffold(
      
      body: product != null ? SingleChildScrollView(
                child: ClipOval(
                    child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                     size: const Size.fromRadius(82),
                     child: Image.network != null
                      ? Image.network( product.image, fit: BoxFit.cover)
                      : const Image(
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          image: AssetImage('assets/profile_placeholder.jpeg')),
             
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ProductCardLayout(chiave: 'Category'.tr, valore:product.name,),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    ProductCardLayout(chiave: 'Stock'.tr, valore: product.stock,),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    ProductCardLayout(chiave: 'Minimum Stock'.tr, valore:product.minStock),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    ProductCardLayout(chiave: 'Expire Date'.tr, valore: '12/05/2024',),  : Container();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like you are not listening to changes to the selectedProduct. To do this you can use an `Obx`. For your example:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx((){
      Product? product = _productController.selectedProduct.value;
      return Scaffold(
        
        body: product != null ? SingleChildScrollView(
                child: ClipOval(
                    child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                     size: const Size.fromRadius(82),
                     child: Image.network != null
                      ? Image.network( product.image, fit: BoxFit.cover)
                      : const Image(
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          image: AssetImage('assets/profile_placeholder.jpeg')),
             
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ProductCardLayout(chiave: 'Category'.tr, valore:product.name,),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    ProductCardLayout(chiave: 'Stock'.tr, valore: product.stock,),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    ProductCardLayout(chiave: 'Minimum Stock'.tr, valore:product.minStock),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    ProductCardLayout(chiave: 'Expire Date'.tr, valore: '12/05/2024',),
```

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that. but there is a slightly delay. It is not perfect. If I open a new product page, I can see the previous product for half second.

Comment: @Giovanni maybe add as first line in `fetchProductByID` `selectedProduct.value = null`

Comment: Alternatively use `Get.create` instead of `Get.put` so a new controller is created for each time you visit that page

Comment: if you meant this: if (!snapshot.exists) {
        selectedProduct.value = null;
      } else {
        var product = Product.fromDocumentSnapshot(snapshot);
        selectedProduct.value = product;
      };
it gives me null error. so I think, this is the reason that I see the delay.

Comment: No I meant added the line `selectedProduct.value = null;` right before `_services.userRef.doc(_services.getUserID())`

Comment: I tried, both with if statement and without. I have the same problem, but instead of the previous product, I see the red null error page for half second, before the right product appear. thanks

Comment: i also have this warning, "The operand can't be null, so the condition is always 'true'. on line : body: product != null ? SingleChildScrollView. Even before apply the changes

Comment: @Giovanni hmm that's strange. I don't see how that could happen

Comment: there 2 possible error: 
1- the Product controller, 
2 - the initstate ```{ productController.fetchProductByID(widget.catID, widget.docProdId)}```, where parameters "widget.catID" and "widget.docProd" are not ready yet, when page is initialised.
So, when I click on selected product from the category page, parameters are still null. should get the fetchProductByID before open the product page